# Most efficient way to bind data in a table into a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have a table that is generated from server side on a partial and rendered using ajax. Because of this I lose binding.

So my only option is to map everything to a JavaScript array and post it.

Is there a way to map everything using jQuery without having to iterate every row then every column and look for each input one by one?

Are there any other options? Perhaps I have to use something like Vue?

Here is my partial:

```
@model Project.Areas.Robotics.Models.ViewModels.DefectRecordViewModel
<form method="post">
    <card>
        <card-header icon="fas fa-thumbs-down" title="Peças NOK">
        </card-header>
        <card-body>



            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <h4>
                        <span class="">
                            <b><i class=""></i>Registo</b> @Model.ProductionRecordId
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="References"></label>
                    <select id="references-nok" asp-items="Model.References" class="custom-select custom-select-sm" onchange="selectReferences(this)">
                        <option value="">--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="tblDefects" class="table table-sm" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead class="bg-olive">
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DefectCodes[0].DefectCodeId)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DefectCodes[0].Quantidade)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DefectCodes[0].Detalhes)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DefectCodes.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DefectCodes[i].DefectCode)
                                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="DefectCodes[i].DefectCodeId" />
                                    <input type="hidden" class="reference-holder" asp-for="DefectCodes[i].ReferenceId" />
                                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="DefectCodes[i].DefectCodeId" />
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                    <input asp-for="DefectCodes[i].Quantidade" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="DefectCodes[i].Quantidade" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input asp-for="DefectCodes[i].Detalhes" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="DefectCodes[i].Detalhes" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>




        </card-body>
        <card-footer>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" data-url="@Url.Page("Index","AddDefectCode")" onclick="addDefectRecord(this)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adicionar</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="hideDetails()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </card-footer>
    </card>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to map everything using jQuery without having to iterate every row then every column and look for each input one by one?

Since you've configured all the `<input/>` with well-formed names, you can build a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an_HTML_form) directly.

```
var formdata = new FormData(someFormElement);
```

For example, add a `submitDefectCode` function to send an ajax request as below:

```js
<script>
function submitDefectCode(element){               // the element is the `<button/>` that is clicked
    var url = element.getAttribute("data-url");
    var form = document.querySelector("form");    // get the `<form>` element
    var formdata = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        method:"post",
        url: url,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formdata,
        success:function(resp){
            console.log(resp);                   // now you get the response
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And trigger this function when clicking the `button`:

```
<button type="button" data-url="@Url.Action("Index","AddDefectCode")" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); submitDefectCode(this);" 
    class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adicionar
</button>
```

Finally, make your server side code to receive the form data with a `[FromForm]` attribute:

```cs
[HttpPost("/AddDefectCode")]     // change this route as you need
public IActionResult TestPost([FromForm]DefectRecordViewModel model)
{
    // ... now you get the model automatically
    return Json(model);
}
```

#### Demo:

Here's a demo screenshot when posting data with multiple table rows:
[image]

---

In case you want to build a javascript array manually, you can use the `FormData.entries()`:

```js
var array= []; 
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
   array.push({key: pair[0], value:pair[1]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand clearly what is Your problem but if You have  large number  of records and You don't want to load complete at once or want to reload your table without reload or all functionality like paging searching and filter you can use data table plugin 
 with server side record manipulation   if this  you are question you can reply  this post so i can give you more example or i will give you some example .for your further understanding .
other wise you can elaborate your question with some screen shot so i can understand your roots of problem and give the best possible answers .

Comment: I tried to use ajax unobtrusive to see if changed anything and it worked, i have all the values on serverside automatically mapped from the form. I suppose my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I used ajax unobtrusive to submit the form on the partial. The model is automatically binded on serverside, no need to do anything manually.